# Insert rows based on cell values of a column

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I am new to VBA, just trying my hands as my requirement is not getting fulfilled  by formulas. 
Depending on the entry in the cell E2..E3..in column E, new rows to be inserted in another sheet.Also copy the value of A, B & C from sheet 1 to A, C, D of sheet 2 respectively. Column B of Sheet 2 will/should automatically generate the line item no.
for example: if E2 = 2 in Sheet1, then 2 new rows to be added with copied data of A2, B2 and C2 of Sheet 1 into Sheet2.

Please check the attached images:
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDdiv.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm9lk.png)

After going through the forum help, I have tried some coding but this for only one cell value, but I need the code to work for each cell value. Which I am not able to do. Also the line item number (Col B) is coming like 3..2..1 not 1..2..3.
Please check the code:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2QjV.png)

Regards,
Krish

Answer (score 0):

```
'Hope this Works for you


Sub transfer_data()

Dim arr() As Variant
Dim cnt, n As Long
arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:E22")))

n = 1
i = 0

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & n).Value = arr(i, 1)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & n).Value = arr(i, 5)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("c" & n).Value = arr(i, 3)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & n).Value = arr(i, 2)
    cnt = arr(i, 5)
    n = n + cnt
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Manoj, this new code is copy pasting the data into sheet2. Not breaking into rows based on value of E2..E3... also not considering the header line/row.      123 2 PL123 MPN1 ..
   
456 1 PL456 MPN2

Comment: Hi Manoj, basically if E2 = 2 and E3=1, your code is creating a line by coping the values and creating 1 blank rows. what I need is it should create if E2 = 2, then it should create 2 rows with values. And in sheet 2 ..column B will reflect the rows no. for each case. So result should be like in sheet2..  123 1 PL123 MPN1  123 2 PL123 MPN1 .. 456 1 PL456 MPN2.